# Filter data from DataTable

Tags: c#, linq

```
DataTable dtt = (DataTable)Session["ByBrand"];
var filldt = (dtt.Select("Price >= " + HiddenField1.Value + " and Price <= " + HiddenField2.Value + "")).CopyToDataTable();
```

this code is working fine when it found values in selected DataTable but it showing error when Values are not found in DataTable. So please tell me how to check if no record found.

Comment: What error are you getting? Seems like the `CopyToDataTable()` extension method should return an empty `DataTable` even if the result was empty instead of erroring out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply check if your Select returns anything?

```
 DataTable dtt = (DataTable)Session["ByBrand"];
 DataRow[] rows = dtt.Select("Price >= " + HiddenField1.Value + " and Price <= " + HiddenField2.Value + "");
if(rows.Length > 0)
{
    var filldt = rows.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Well, the Linq example from Tim is really nice, but to complete my answer.
The Select method returns Always a DataRow array also if there is no row selected, but then you cannot ask to build a datatable from this empty array. Think about it. What schema the CopyToDataTable should build for the resulting table if no rows are present in the array?

Answer (score 6):

You have tagged *Linq* but you are using `DataTable.Select` which is an old method to filter a `DataTable`. Use [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) and the strongyl typed [`Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) extension method.

```
decimal priceFrom = decimal.Parse(HiddenField1.Value);
decimal priceTo = decimal.Parse(HiddenField2.Value);

var dtFiltered = dtt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<decimal>("Price") >= priceFrom 
               && row.Field<decimal>("Price") <= priceTo))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Presuming that the type of the column is `decimal`, if it's a different type you need to use that in `Field` or convert it first.

Note that you need to add `System.Linq`(file) and a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`(project).

**Update**

> but it showing error when Values are not found in DataTable

`CopyToDataTable` throws an exception if the input sequence is empty. In my opinion the best approach is to handle that case separately:

```
DataTable tblFiltered = dtt.Clone(); // clones only structure not data
var filteredRows = dtt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<decimal>("Price") >= priceFrom 
               && row.Field<decimal>("Price") <= priceTo));
if(filteredRows.Any())
{
    tblFiltered = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

or this approach that might be more efficient since it doesn't need to use `Any` which can cause an additional full enumeration in worst case:

```
foreach(DataRow row in filteredRows)
{
    tblFiltered.ImportRow(row);
}
```