# Filtering DataTable Getting exception

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I am using DataTable in my application.In that i am tying to filter using select statement.My code is Like below.

```
string expression = string.Format("DateTime > '{0}' and DateTime < '{1}'", abc.Min, abc.Max);
DataTable table = _TrailTable.Select(expression).CopyToDataTable();
```

My application works well when the values are within the range.But it is giving exception when **_TrailTable** value are not within the **expression** range,in this case it is giving ***The source contains no DataRows*** exception how to avoid this?

Comment: what do u want to achieve when its not in expected range?

Comment: What exception do you get? Please edit that into your question.

Comment: @Neel It should not be crashed.table should be either null or empty

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess you can handle this exception using try catch block as shown below :-

```
DataTable table;
try 
{
   string expression = string.Format("DateTime > '{0}' and DateTime < '{1}'", abc.Min, abc.Max);
   table = _TrailTable.Select(expression).CopyToDataTable();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   table = null;
}
```

Comment: I did this one .Here i am asking wheather is it possible to avoid applying try catch? why it is crashing here

Comment: Ok i already applied try catch.i will going to use in the same way,thanks for guiding

Comment: I looked more carefully at the exceptions raised by select, and the exception is because of the copy not the select - I think the answer at the following link is the correct one:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16894489/filter-data-from-datatable